# CSS Flex: Row inside a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble styling a row inside a row using `flex`.

```css
.row, [class*='col-'] {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.col-6 {
 flex-basis: 50%;
 max-width: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-6" style="background-color:red;">
  
  <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-6" style="background-color:green;">
    should be 25%
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue;">
    another 25%
   </div>
   
  </div>
 
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-6" style="background-color:gray;">
  Right half
 </div>

</div> <!-- /.row -->

<p>The red background should not be seen, since the green and blue should each take up 50% of the red's space...</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `flex` will fill the space (based on the basis), you don't need another `row`.  In fact, you don't need rows very often in flex-box layouts.

If you take out the nested row, this seems to do what you are after:

```css
.row, [class*='col-'] {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.col-6 {
 flex-basis: 50%;
 max-width: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-6" style="background-color:red;">
       
   <div class="col-6" style="background-color:green;">
    should be 25%
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue;">
    another 25%
   </div>
 
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-6" style="background-color:gray;">
  Right half
 </div>

</div> <!-- /.row -->

<p>The red background should not be seen, since the green and blue should each take up 50% of the red's space...</p>
```

Comment: Oh, okay, nice. Thank you. I'm so used to a table style layout where you have to keep specifying rows.